# jQuery .toggleClass() does not toggle off the class after its toggled on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In order to change the color scheme of the site, I've added an alternate class that was suppose to toggle on and off through a button with the usage of `.toggleClass()`, however, when I do toggle the class on, it doesn't seem to toggle back off when I click on the button again.

CSS

```
/*
Alternate color (dark) scheme
*/
 body.dark {
    background-color:#1e1d1b;
}
body.dark #main {
    background:#292826 url(background_dark_slice.jpg) repeat-x;
}
body.dark #main .container {
    background-image:url(background_dark.jpg);
}
body.dark #footer {
    background-image:url(background_dark_footer.jpg);
}
body.dark ul#menu li a.active, ul#menu li a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var button = document.querySelector('.forjs button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        $('.dark').toggleClass();
    });
  });
```

Comment: What class is it supposed to toggle?

Comment: In your case if you want to remove the dark class, you could either use `$('.dark').removeClass('dark');` or `$('.dark').toggleClass('dark');` (which would simply have an additional internal `if($(this).hasClass('className')` check).

Comment: It is supposed to toggle the `.dark` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the `toggleClass()` function you must be provided with a `string` representing the class to be checked for, and to be added/removed if present/absent: toggleClass('class');
2. If you were to do something like `$('.myClass').toggleClass('myClass')` - it would only work the first time you fire it - as the second time, there would be no more elements with `.myClass` in the document - you just removed it in the previous function call.
3. As you have not provided the HTML also, we cannot know for sure that the `document.querySelector('.forjs button')` is accurate - please test if this is so, or provide the adequate HTML code.
4. In your CSS, you have defined the changes to take place when the `body` has a class of `.dark` : `body.dark {}`. So, in your case, the `toggleClass()` should be applied to the `$(body)` : `$('body').toggleClass('dark');`

You end function should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var button = document.querySelector('.forjs button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('dark');
    });
});
```

As you are mixing JQuery and vanilla JS, it would be advisable to keep consistent with one or the other.

Vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelector('.forjs button').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
```

Jquery :

```
$('.forjs button').on('click', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('dark');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead: `$('body').toggleClass('dark');`

Comment: Hi Patrick and welcome to SO. It seems the author specifically wants to target the `.dark` selector in his post whereas your code would switch the class of the HTML body. I don't think this is what the question author is looking for.

Comment: From the CSS he provided, I guessed that ".dark" is the theme-class he wants to be toggled.

Comment: You are right, I had overlooked that. So your answer would be perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.dark').toggleClass('class_name');
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/
`toggleClass` have parameter more than zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the class name you want to toggle as a parameter. Otherwise you’ll toggle all the classes on the element (eg remove them) meaning the the selector will no longer work...
 Add another class (or id) to your element and call using that

```
$(".toggle").toggleClass("dark")
```

Comment: The class provided inside the `toggleClass(className)` does not have the CSS class dot in front as it only and specifically handles classes. I already fixed this for you in your code.

Comment: Cheers. Was editing myself when you fixed. On phone and have fat fingers :D